# Merging 3 sql views into 1 query using a look up table SQL

Tags: sql, select, sum

I need to sum estimated minutes of time from 3 different queries into 1 sql query.
I have 3 views (one for parts cut on Machine A by job, one for parts cut on Machine B by job, and one cut on Machine C by job). I have another table that has a list of all the parts that have an estimated cut time, we will call TableA. I have written three different queries using the views that left join onto TableA to sum the cut times. However, I want a query that returns a table with a list of jobs and the estimated cut time for each job by machine. So each row would have the job followed by three estimated cut times broken down by each machine.

```
 --------Machine A-------
 SELECT 
 sum(TableA.[minutes]) as 'total', MachineA.JobNum
 FROM MachineA
 LEFT JOIN TableA on
 TableA.Part = MachineA.PART
 WHERE TableA.OP = 10 and OP_DISABLE IS NULL
 group by MachineA.Job

 --------Machine B-------
 SELECT 
 sum(TableA.[minutes]) as 'total', MachineB.JobNum
 FROM MachineB
 LEFT JOIN TableA on
 TableA.Part = MachineB.PART
 WHERE TableA.OP = 10 and OP_DISABLE IS NULL
 group by MachineB.Job

 --------Machine C-------
 SELECT 
 sum(TableA.[minutes]) as 'total', MachineC.JobNum
 FROM MachineC
 LEFT JOIN TableA on
 TableA.Part = MachineC.PART
 WHERE TableA.OP = 10 and OP_DISABLE IS NULL
 group by MachineC.Job
```

Example Table I am looking for

```
 Job | MachinA_Time | MachineB_Time | MachineC_Time|
 ----------------------------------------------------
 123 | 345          | 512           | 452          |
 124 | 215          | 351           | 356
```

Comment: just join on job #?

Comment: @long What do you mean join on job? How would I make all of these into one query?

Comment: Thanks for all the replies guys I really appreciate it. I am going to run all 3 solutions and make sure they all work and comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `UNION` you can do this:

```
SELECT JobNum
  ,MAX(MachinA_Time) AS MachinA_Time
  ,MAX(MachinB_Time) AS MachinB_Time
  ,MAX(MachinC_Time) AS MachinC_Time
FROM
(

    SELECT MachineA.JobNum, sum(TableA.[minutes]) as MachinA_Time, NULL AS MachinB_Time, NULL AS MachinA_Time
     FROM MachineA 
    LEFT JOIN TableA on TableA.Part = MachineA.PART
     WHERE TableA.OP = 10 and OP_DISABLE IS NULL
     group by MachineA.Job
    UNION ALL
     SELECT MachineB.JobNum, NULL, sum(TableA.[minutes]), NULL
     FROM MachineB
     LEFT JOIN TableA on
     TableA.Part = MachineB.PART
     WHERE TableA.OP = 10 and OP_DISABLE IS NULL
     group by MachineB.Job
    UNION ALL
     SELECT MachineC.JobNum, NULL, NULL, sum(TableA.[minutes])
     FROM MachineC
     LEFT JOIN TableA on
     TableA.Part = MachineC.PART
     WHERE TableA.OP = 10 and OP_DISABLE IS NULL
     group by MachineC.Job

) AS t
GROUP BY JobNum
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can save unnecessary joins by using conditional aggregation and `UNION` , since the format is the same

```
SELECT p.jobnum,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.machine = 'A' THEN t.[minutes] END) as machineA_Time,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.machine = 'B' THEN t.[minutes] END) as machineB_Time,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.machine = 'C' THEN t.[minutes] END) as machineC_Time
FROM(SELECT s.minutes,s.part,'A' as machine FROM MachineA s
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT s.minutes,s.part,'B' FROM MachineB s
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT s.minutes,s.part,'C' FROM MachineC s) t
JOIN TableA p
 ON(p.part = t.part)
WHERE p.op = 10
GROUP BY p.jobnum
```

This query may need some extra adjustments, as I don't know where `OP_DISABLE IS NULL` came from .

Answer (score 1):

Just join each result based on the sharing job#:

```
WITH MachineA
AS
(
 SELECT 
 sum(TableA.[minutes]) as 'total', MachineA.JobNum
 FROM MachineA
 LEFT JOIN TableA on
 TableA.Part = MachineA.PART
 WHERE TableA.OP = 10 and OP_DISABLE IS NULL
 group by MachineA.Job
 ),
 MachineB
 as
 (-
 SELECT 
 sum(TableA.[minutes]) as 'total', MachineB.JobNum
 FROM MachineB
 LEFT JOIN TableA on
 TableA.Part = MachineB.PART
 WHERE TableA.OP = 10 and OP_DISABLE IS NULL
 group by MachineB.Job
 ),
  MachineC
 as
(
 SELECT 
 sum(TableA.[minutes]) as 'total', MachineC.JobNum
 FROM MachineC
 LEFT JOIN TableA on
 TableA.Part = MachineC.PART
 WHERE TableA.OP = 10 and OP_DISABLE IS NULL
 group by MachineC.Job
 )

 SELECT A.JobNum as Job, MachineA.total as MachineATime,  MachineB.total as MachineBTime, MachineC.total as MachineCTime
 FROM MachineA as A
 INNER JOIN MachineB as B
 ON B.JobNum = A.JobNum
 INNER JOIN MachineC as C
 ON C.JobNum = A.JobNum
```

Comment: yeah, I am just using the dumbest way xD, yours is way elegant and delicate xD

Comment: @Cheddar, np, but you may seek a more efficient way like getting the output from one query, like the others' answer.